# in HTML page can we use jsp code

Tags: html, jsp

In `page.html` we can use javascript code, I accept that, but can we use jsp and tld files in html files.

Please explain.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Perhaps more details?

Comment: Are you running locally or on a server ?

Comment: You need Tomcat web server to execute JSP script

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to run JSP pages from a server that does not allow it or do you want users to request .html pages and be served JSP from the server?

Comment: Just rename `page.html` to `page.jsp` or map `JspServlet` on `*.html`.

Comment: in project the page is given as page.html it is like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/print.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any server-side code would need to be executed on the server, not in the browser.  There's a hard separation between the server-side processing and the client-side processing.  So the JSP code wouldn't be able to interact with the JavaScript code or anything like that.

In order for server-side code to be executed in an HTML file before rendering it to the browser, your server would need to be configured to process that code.  It would be a matter of configuring your web server, whichever one you're using.  By default I imagine it just returns .html files to the browser without any server-side processing.  But you can configure your web server to treat .html files just like it would JSP files.

Keep in mind that you would need to treat those .html files like you normally would JSP files.  It would have to match the same conventions for separating client-side code from server-side code.

Comment: Thank i understand your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your web server to map the `text/html` content type to JSP, you can.

Answer (score 0):

No. JSP pages are executed on the server side and produce HTML, which is sent to the browser. JSP acts just like PHP in this regard, essentially "rendering" some HTML code and sending it off to the user. You can't embed JSP code in the HTML and send it off to the user - their browser will just do nothing with it.